# Jumping over missing rows in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of countries and sectors and for each of them I would like to plot some variables in my dataset. However, some of the countries do not have specific sectors. How can I avoid the error that stops generating the graphs after the first missing pair is reached. For example I do not get the graphs after it reaches country=="JPN" and sector=="COAL" (i.e., Japan does not have a coal sector). Is there a way to ask it to jump from the missing rows, other than generating a new dataframe, which contains all of the countries and sectors including missing values.

```
sectorlist <- list("LIVE","CROP","FORS","COAL","OIL","GAS")

countrylist <- list("CAN","USA","CHN","EUR","MEX","JPN","ANZ","ROE","RUS","ASI","IND")


for(country_name in countrylist) {
  for(sector_name in sectorlist) {

ggplot()

}
}
```

Comment: You can use they keyword `next` to jump to the next iteration of the for loop. You just need to figure out how to detect if the particular iteration should be skipped, and have something like `if(code_to_tell_if_this_sector_is_missing) {next}`

Comment: Thanks Gregor! Just the problem is that I do not have those missing rows in the dataset so something like `if(is.na(country) & is.na(sector)) {next}` does not work for me!

Comment: But there's going to be **some** way to tell. Maybe it's `if (nrow(this_subset_of_data) == 0) {next}` or `if(length(something) == 0) {next}` ... We can't really help more than that without sample data.